# Instagram html response asks for login on cloud servers

Tags: docker, go, kubernetes, cors, instagram

I have a code which sends request to Instagram as follows:

```
url := "https://www.instagram.com/cristiano"
method := "GET"
client := &http.Client{}
req, err := http.NewRequest(method, url, nil)
res, err := client.Do(req)
```

After receiving the html response I simply check for og tages (like og:title) in the response. If og tags are there, it means username `cristiano` exists on the instagram.

This code works well in my local PC. But when I run it on cloud server it doesnot give the expected output. Instagram asks for login on cloud servers.   `<meta content="Welcome back to Instagram. Sign in to see what your friends, family and interests have been capturing and sharing around the world." name="description" />`

From local also, I'm not using any cookies/headers. I'm curious to know why Instagram is asking for login on cloud server but not on local PC.
I have also tried running same code on docker desktop too. There also it worked fine. which emplies that it can work fine in isolated enviroment.

there is a little difference in response headers that I found.

1. for cloud server: Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy:[unsafe-none]
2. for local PC: Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy:[same-origin-allow-popups]

Not sure how above header works and how it can effect the output

I have tried comparing the responses and headers at both the places (local / cloud).
I expected that local and cloud server will result in same output as the code is same and it also works on docker desktop

Comment: Your requests include an IP address. I suspect the Instagram service is forcing auth on IP blocks where scrapers/bots are suspected and cloud providers would be likely sources of this traffic (since Instagram end users aren't customarily server machines)

Comment: What can be done in this case ? any ideas ? @DazWilkin

Comment: You will need to auth your requests. [Instagram Platform](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram) provides 2 APIs and both provide auth mechanisms. I'm unfamiliar with them but they should provide a mechanism to create API tokens that you should use. Ideally, there will be a Go SDK for Instagram. Do **not** use 3rd-party SDKs that require you to provide usernames and passwords.